# Saving a TIFF file with band names

Tags: geotiff-tiff, imagery

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a TIFFTAG when saving a TIFF file (I'm using the C/libtiff interface) that will give a name to each band?

Some kind of per-band TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION is what I'm after. I checked the documentation but can't find anything - however, I have seen TIFFs saved with band names so I assume it's possible somehow.

I am not using rasterio.

Comment: I thought this looked like it might be off-topic but since Remote Sensing is on-topic the library being asked about appears to be too: http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/

Comment: I posted here as I've only ever seen per-band names for RS data: Usually a name with the central wavelength of other important feature of the channel.

Comment: It sounds to me a bit like a simplified case of Raster Attribute Table (RAT). GDAL seems to support them only for Idrisi, GeoRaster, KEA and HFA (Erdas) formats. However, if TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION is enough for you it can be handled with the GDAL GeoTIFF driver http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. Reading the source code can help you with your own programming.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using that tifftag. I'm beginning to think that the files I saw with per-band names were using some very software-specific thing. Can't find any more info about them.